# Making runs of a color when using mouse to draw in Processing

Tags: random, colors, drawing, processing

I'm trying to create code in processing that allows for runs of a certain color while drawing with the mouse. Right now the color is selected by a random function that randoms a float between 1 and 0 then based on if that float is above or below .5 the color is chosen. The way I was going to make runs of a color is have a for loop below where the random float is chosen and then have the color functions within this, however if I put this for loop in void draw() it doesn't work because this is recalled at the frame rate. If I put it in void mouseDragged() the same problem occurs in that it's only called once each time the mouse is dragged.

Basically I'm trying to figure out a method to have one of two colors randomly selected then have that color drawn for a certain number of frames (as the mouse is dragged) then after that number of frames randomly select one of the two colors again and repeat.

Here's the code I have for drawing right now (where the color is randomly determined each frame):

```java
void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  background(000);
}

void draw() {  
}

void mouseDragged () {
  //assigns random float between 0 and 1 which is used for deciding which color to paint
  float x = random(0, 1);

  //assigns random stroke value
  stroke(random(100, 200));

  if (x <= .5) {
    fill(20, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, mouseX/4, mouseY/4);
  }

  if (x > .5) {
    fill(random(220, 250), random(20, 50), random(220, 250));
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, mouseX/4, mouseY/4);
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a boolean variable that you use to toggle 'states' (using the first colour or the second). If you want to change swap colours based on a number of frames, you can use [frameCount](http://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html).

```
color a,b;
boolean useFirst = true;

void setup(){
  size(1000,1000);
  background(0);
  resetColors();
}
void resetColors(){
  a = color(20, 255, 255);
  b = color(random(220, 250), random(20, 50), random(220, 250));
}
void draw(){
  if(frameCount % 20 == 0) useFirst = !useFirst;//toggle colors every 20 frames
}
void mouseDragged () {
  if(useFirst) fill(a);
  else         fill(b);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, mouseX/4, mouseY/4);
}
void keyPressed(){
  resetColors();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this was exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to processing so I wasn't aware of frameCount, but now I am! (Oops.)

Comment: Glad to help! Also, if you need a similar functionality but based on time, rather than frames, have a look at the [millis()](http://processing.org/reference/millis_.html) function.